# SQL Server: How to select rows which contain value comprising of only one digit

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to write a SQL query that only returns rows where a specific column (let's say 'amount' column) contains numbers comprising of only one digit, e.g. only '1's (1111111...) or only '2's (2222222...), etc.

In addition, 'amount' column contains numbers with decimal points as well and these kind of values should also be returned, e.g. 1111.11, 2222.22, etc

Comment: What have you tried? This isn't a code-writing service. Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Tried the following: select * from [tablename] where amount = REPLICATE ('1', len(amount))

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make the query generic that you don't have to specify each possible digit you could change the where to the following:

```
WHERE LEN(REPLACE(REPLACE(amount,LEFT(amount,1),''),'.','') = 0
```

This will always use the first digit as comparison for the rest of the string

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server, then you can try this script:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
        SELECT CAST(amount AS VARCHAR(30)) AS amount
        FROM TableName
)t
WHERE LEN(REPLACE(REPLACE(amount,'1',''),'.','') = 0 OR
      LEN(REPLACE(REPLACE(amount,'2',''),'.','') = 0
```

Comment: Hi, tried as you suggested, and the following error was raised and underlined in red in where clause: 'an expression of non boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected'

Comment: Yes, only changed column/table names

Comment: Its very straight foreword Select command. you may missing some thing while replacing column/tablename

Answer (score 0):

I tried like this in place of 1111111 replace with column name:

```
Select replace(Str(1111111, 12, 2),0,left(11111,1))
```